# Footer menu same as Menu

Tags: website-design, menu, css, responsive

The links which are in the menu are replicated in the footer menu. Is placing same menu links in the footer redundant or is it a bad practice in web design or development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the footer and header links like the pagination of a data table. If you need to scroll to the top every time to get to the next page, that is a problem for the user. So you define a second pagination at the bottom of the table to enable the user switch pages at which end of the table the user is near to.

So my two cents, if you have a long content that makes the pages scroll (to the point where the header becomes completely invisible), there's nothing wrong to add the header links to the footer. But otherwise, two same structure in the same viewport is completely redundant and disturbing.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site, Mohammed!

Here's my opinion:

- In general, providing multiple options to achieve a goal is good. For example, in addition to menus or buttons, there often is a keyboard shortcut.
- There is a danger, however, when it is not clear to the user *why* there are two options to access a feature. Users will then wonder what the difference is and sometimes even invent a different interpretation although there is none.

In summary, provided the two options are different enough, it's ok. What "diffferent enough" means, depends on the users and use case. From your question, though, putting the same options into menu and footer bar runs the danger of confusion - is my guess.